# mysql installation on mac, access denied

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I have never used MySQL before and know very little about the Mac terminal. I am trying to establish my first connection in MySQL Workbench to MySQL Community server installed on my Mac. It is asking for a password:

[image]

Entering the password that was provided in a previous popup dialogue box does not work. There was a message at some point about needing to change that temporary password, but I can no longer figure a way to access that message for any potential instructions.

Clicking on the "i" information button in the connection box says there is no password stored. I don't know if that means: not saved in a key chain, no password associated with the account, or no password associated with the user named "root".

[image]

I've experimented in all ways I can think of in this dialogue box as well:
[image]

It seems some commands have to be executed with the server running vs not as well. I have at least found how to turn it off/on in the System Preferences! I have read as much as I can comprehend in the MySQL documentation/tutorials, articles I found on the Internet, videos I've watched. I'm trying to use the terminal to either set, change, or determine if there is a password, but I keep hitting roadblocks before getting to the ALTER USER commands, like:

```
✘-1 /usr/local/mysql/bin 
11:57 $ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
sudo: mysqld_safe: command not found

✘-127 /usr/local/mysql/bin 
11:58 $ mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I'm just copying characters into the terminal that I see in videos and articles, but don't know what this means. I've looked up Unix commands on line and am getting some of it slowly.

Ultimately, I just wanted to experiment with MySQL and try to diagram out and create a test database. But as a complete newb, I can't seem to even log in, lol. I wish I could ask a more specific question, but I'm not even sure where to start. Thanks for any pointers you can offer.

PS: That X-127 stuff in the code is I think from something an employer asked me install once to help making using the Terminal easier. But I don't quite know what it does, or if it's interfering.

**EDIT:**
Here's the result when trying to Test Connection, and then entering the supplied password:

[image]

Comment: Instead of `UPDATE`, try using the [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) command.

Comment: Thanks, however I get the same syntax error. I've also tried double quotes instead of single quotes around 'password' and/or 'root' with no luck.  `✘-INT /usr/local/mysql/bin 
13:13 $ mysql> GRANT mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD(“password”) WHERE User='root';
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: Please, *read the documentation* and use the command correctly. I linked to it for that specific reason. You don't just have at it randomly.

Comment: OK, so step by step, your link says "To use GRANT, you must have the GRANT OPTION privilege,..."  I don't know if I have the GRANT OPTION privilege. I asked Google: [http://serverfault.com/questions/117525/how-can-i-show-users-privileges-in-mysql]. Here's the result: `✘-127 /usr/local/mysql/bin 
13:24 $ mysql> SHOW GRANTS [FOR user]`
-bash: SHOW: Permission denied`

Comment: You need to be logged in as `root` with whatever password was assigned by default. Normally it's installed with no password, it's your responsibility to set one. You may need to uninstall, delete the MySQL data files, and try again.

Comment: I can't log in. That's the issue. When I enter the supplied password I get the following dialogue pop up: "Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" (screenshot added above)

Comment: Have you tried without a password?

Comment: Yes. The resulting message is the same, except YES is NO.

Comment: Like I said, uninstall, expunge the MySQL data files, and try again. Also be sure you don't have some other MySQL service running that you're inadvertently connecting to.

Comment: Success! I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryvNDIX3gQA) to help navigate to the proper directory in the terminal - 00:25 secs. Then [this site](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x) for the uninstall procedure. I uninstalled MySQL Workbench as well. Reinstalled MySQL Community Server. Reinstalled MySQL Workbench. Received a new password. This time upon Test Connection, there was a prompt to change the temporary password. I did. It worked. Thank you @tadman.

Comment: Right on. Hope that helps get you going.